# Correct use of multiple 'will ' and 'and'

Tags: usage

Which one of the following is correct? Could you please tell me the reason for it as well?

1. I will come and will paint your fence and will repair your car.
2. I will come, paint your fence and repair your car.
3. I will come, will paint your fence and will repair your car.

Comment: I would say all 3 are correct but No.2 is most natural

Comment: It's not ungrammatical to repeat, but it not idiomatic.  Number 2 is the only option that works.

Comment: You could say "Ill come paint your fence and repair your car." The first "will" applies to the whole sentence. @BruceMurray I think 2 works, but only if the comma is removed.

Comment: Thanks @Jack O'Flaherty, is comma required if it is 'fix your radio' insted of 'come'? Is the following correct - I will fix your radio, paint your fence and repair your car

Comment: @Ajay Yes. In that sentence, the three items are in a series. They should be separated by commas, except (optionally)  the one before the "and".